# How to read Arabic properties from conf.properties java

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, properties, resourcebundle

I have a java project, there is a configuration file (c.conf.properties) file.
I have successfully read the properties when they have English values.

But when I add Arabic values, then it can't display these values on Arabic.
First at the conf file:

```
ar_msg=\u0644\u0627
```

Java code :

```
Properties prop= new Properties();
InputStream input =null;
//Read configuration file
input = new FileInputStream( "c.conf.properties");
prop.load(input);
ar_msg= prop.get("ar_msg").toString();
```

when I print this Arabic property (ar_msg), then it will print it as (???).
So how to display the values in Arabic in the conf file? and how to read them as Arabic encoding?

Comment: Where are you printing these properties to ?

Comment: using::  System.out.println(ar_msg);

Comment: Maybe your console is unable to print those characters, try printing to a file (with an appropriate charset which supports those characters) and check if everything looks right.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, the key spelling was entered incorrectly.

not prop.get("ar_msg") you should type below

```
ar_msg= prop.get("ar_v").toString();
```

then, printing works well in my terminal...

Comment: sorry it is my mistake, I have used the same name, see modification.